# How to enable the native GNOME Files (Nautilus) look?

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus

I've just installed Ubuntu again after 2 years (forced for internal reasons). I see that Unity Desktop Environment advanced a lot, and it's quite usable now.

However, I've come from Gnome desktop. And, **I really miss the beautiful look of native GNOME Files (Nautilus):**

[image]

Is there any way to install Files with native GNOME 3 titlebar?

Comment: An ANSWER IS added

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool`

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Open it
3. Change the theme to *Adwaita*, Icon theme to *Adwaita* and Cursor theme to *Adwaita* as well.

The default Gnome look will be restored.